# What is the opposite of 'identity' in this case?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

**I am looking for a word that describes the exact opposite of identity.**

I have this sentence that says *The identity operator returns true if the operands are strictly equal.*

In other terms is there a word for *not strictly equal* / *strictly unequal*?

There is an operator that does the opposite: *The **opposite word** operator returns true if the operands are strictly unequal.*

I tried to google the antonyms and such, but none of the proposed words match or satisfy this case in my opinion. **Or did you see or do you think one them could be used?**

- difference
- dissimilarity
- opposite
- non-identity
- *other suggestions*?

---

Definitions for this case:

*equal* - only very few characteristics cannot be in common.

*strictly equal* - all characteristics are in common.

*unequal* - only very few characteristics can be in common.

*not strictly equal* - none of the characteristics are in common.

I don't want it to be a Math question. They use symbols not words.

Comment: This is surely a maths-specific usage, not relevant to other English, and would be better asked on Maths SE.

Comment: What is the difference between *unequal* and *strictly unequal*?

Comment: @vladkornea In some computer languages, it possible that a comparison of two variable of different types will yield equality.  A "strict" comparison won't yield equality unless the two variables are of the same type.  So strict equality implies equality, but not vice versa.

Comment: I want it to be more general @deadrat - I do not want to restrict the creativity of the users. Please see definitions in updated question. The example sentence is merely an example. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Elyasin You defined the term as "none of the characteristics are in common". This is different from "not identical". Can you clarify which you mean?

Comment: That's how I would like to describe it. If non-identical does not fit so be it. That's basically my question.

Comment: @Elyasin I'm trying to identify a context in which this concept would be meaningful. For example, the string '1' is equal to the integer 1 but is not identical to it because strings and integers are different types. If you were to use your fictional operator to compare '1' and 1, what would the return value be? They have different types, but the same value. So it would be *false*, right? If you're comparing '1' and '2', then it would be *false*. If comparing integer 1 and string '2', then it would be *true*. Can you think of any scenario in which this is useful?

Comment: @vladkornea Good thinking. I'd like to avoid to think in those terms only. I was hoping to leverage the creativity of English speakers that are not biased towards exact science. Taking your example the scientists/engineers decided the following: the number 1 and the character "1" are equal, but not strictly equal. The character "1" and the character "2" are neither of both. The number 1 and the character "2" are neither also. I was hoping to be able to find a word for that one operator that inverses the described behaviour. Till now *non-identity* seems the closest, but I am not happy with it.

Comment: The Collins definition for [**nonfungible**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/business-english/nonfungible) hasn't caught up with [David Deutsch's use of the term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fungibility#Examples), but I suggest it's a contender for OP's context. In his universe, you can't get any more "identical" than *fungible*, so any difference at all would make something *nonfungible*.

Comment: The identity operator in C is `==`.  The opposite operator is `!=` -- "not equal".  (I think you misunderstand what "strictly equal" commonly means.)

Comment: It is impossible to have "none of the characteristics in common", unless perhaps one of the items being compared does not exist at all.  If they exist on a given computer, that is a common characteristic.

Comment: I wonder if you aren't looking for terminology to define "degree of similarity".  Eg, two images might be bit-for-bit identical, might vary slightly (different resolution, eg), might vary more significantly (the same objects photographed from different angles), or might be totally different.  (As it is, your question makes no sense.)

Comment: To be as precise as possible I'd use **not identity** in my logic class. Also, **nonfungible** works for elements in the physical universe, but that does not apply in this specific case, neither do other comments. This question is not an English question, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a coder, when I think of an "identity operator" I put it into coding terms where there might, for example, be an associated truth table that identifies how it is evaluated.

and, in most coding languages, there is a Negation operator that can be combined with it to show indicate the opposite usage. The obvious example in most languages being equal "=" versus Not equal "!=". where the exclamation point indicates that the associated truth table for this expression must the opposite.

I'm not sure I've ever seen a single operator that implies "NOT identity", so if you have created one - congratulations! you get to name it.

Hmmm.... the disparity operator?

And at that, I sure wouldn't want to have to have the debate on exactly what percentage of characteristics have to differ before you flip from equal to unequal. And are the characteristics weighted as to their importance in determining when something ceases to be equal? Writing precise definitions without precise meanings (exactly how many is "a few"?) is a tough thing to do!

Comment: The definitions in the OP kind of fail, but *disparity* is precise, in that it covers there being two objects (true) or there being one object and null (true).  I suggest *plurality* because it is descriptive of the state of having two equal objects with disparate identities, but *disparity* covers that *and* having one object with nothing. So +1 dispite throwing *plurality* out there as well.

Comment: Not easy to digest, but I think your word choice is the most appropriate in my opinion. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**[Non-identity/strict not equal:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)** The non-identity operator returns true if the operands are not equal and/or not of the same type.

Answer (score 2):

The first word that comes to mind is **inequality** operator. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operator) makes a distinction between *equality* and *inequality*; the question is if there is any real difference between your *identity* and the concept of *equality*.

[Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz250sf.aspx) calls the **!=** operator the *inequality* operator, and it seems to do what you describe.

(I would rephrase "strictly unequal" to "not strictly equal" to indicate the exact opposite behaviour, by the way.)

Comment: Thank you @oerkelens - I updated my question with more details. Sorry having been so imprecise.

Comment: It is more analogous to the ! operator, the **not** operator since it is the opposite of identity, so !value.

Answer (score 2):

As the terms are commonly used in most programming languages, "equal" means that the observable values of the two entities being compared are identical.  "Strictly equal" means that the two entities are, in fact, the *same* entity, but presumably reached using two different pointer/reference variables.

Your definitions don't make any sense.

Comment: In PHP and JS, "equal" means "equal value after type coercion", and "identical" means "same type and equal value". What language are you talking about? http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: @vladkornea - Strongly-typed object-oriented languages like Objective-C and Java, for one.

Answer (score 1):

> The **difference** operator returns true if and only if the operands are not strictly equal.

Comment: can you let me know where i can read upon this? any reference? is it established usage?

Comment: I thought you knew the semantics and just needed a name.  PHP calls the operator "not identical" for non-arrays and "non-identity" for arrays.  Check php.net for details.

Comment: Most people interpret "difference operator" to be `-`, the subtraction operator.

Comment: @HotLicks Really?  I've never heard or read anything in which subtraction was referred to as "a difference operator."  If this is indeed about a comparison operator in a programming language, I would think that the fact that subtraction isn't commutative would make that unlikely.  But maybe it's just me.

Comment: @deadrat - "difference" is sort of like "quotient" and "remainder" which are the results of division and modulus operations.  I also, like HotLicks, think of it as being a scalar value and not a boolean.

Comment: @stevesliva Certainly true for arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an established word for it, but maybe you could create one. Two points on the Earth's surface are *antipodal* if they are as far away as possible. So you could call this the *antipodal* operator.

Comment: That's what I was hoping. You're being creative. Thanks. Will think about it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "opposite" of identity. Whether two entities are identical is a true or false question. If they are identical, then all their properties are the same. Otherwise, at least one of their properties is different. However, you are not looking for this mere negation (non-identity), but for the far more exotic meaning of "not even one of their properties is the same". Let's call it anti-identity.

Entities in general can have countless properties. For instance, is a dog anti-identical to a keyboard? Both are physical entities, so that is one property which they do have in common, so they are not anti-identical. This sort of consideration makes this concept meaningless, except in narrow contexts like software. In that context variables have countable properties such as "value" and "type", and you could go through all of them and make sure that every single one of them is different. Here the concept can be made *meaningful*, but it would be *useless*, because it answers a question which it is never useful to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You could call it a *plurality* operator, in the sense that it returns true if you have a plurality of objects in the comparison.

***plurality***

> The state of being plural [more than one]

(Definitions of plurality and plural from [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plurality) combined).

This is an *English* answer despite alluding to  "objects" and return values.  The OP's definitions of equal/strictly equal/etc make no logical sense to me in any context, but *an* opposite of the state of having one identity is the state of being plural.  However the state of *not being* complicates the idea of calling plurality a true antonym of identity, which is why *disparity*, as suggested in another answer, is perhaps more precise.

But if you want to focus on there being multiple instances of perhaps equally-valued objects, *plurality* may be what you're looking for.